# ENABLE resizing or scrolling of activity on keyboard pop up

Tags: android, android-layout

I've seen numerous threads on how to disable standard Android behavior of scrolling active text field or resizing current activity when on-screen keyboard pops up, yet my problem is exactly opposite. Neither scrolling nor resizing happens in my app.

What do I have to do to implement proper behavior?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?colorPrimary">

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="200dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/lewa_lista_size"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="?xenoPanelBackgroundColor"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/playlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chwytak"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tlo_kropek"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/kropki"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/uchwyt_szuflady_height"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@mipmap/kropki" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/wypelniaczGorny"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/playlistAB"
                style="?xenoActionBarTheme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/chwytak"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/wypelniacz"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="?xenoPanelBackgroundColor"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_above="@id/wypelniacz"
                android:layout_below="@id/playlistAB"
                android:background="?xenoPanelBackgroundColor"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is your activity fullscreen?

Comment: Well - yes. Are there any other kinds of activities?

Comment: Paste your activity and layout code here. If your activity is fullscreen then your layout will not resize on keyboard popup.

Comment: Main activity is definitely too big for pasting here. But look at the layout.

Comment: Add scrollview to the layout.

Comment: Should NestedScrollView work the same? (because it doesn't...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an windowSoftInputMode property for activiy in manifest here is example

```
 <activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:name=".YourActivity"></activity>
```

How the main window of the activity interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The setting for this attribute affects two things:
The state of the soft keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes the focus of user attention.
The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.

here u get more info https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

you can get suitable attribute according to your requirement

Comment: Yes that's almost acceptable: the view scrolls indeed but just to make the edited line appear above the keyboard. If there's more editable lines below the current line I'm unable to scroll the view up, though. I have to pop down the soft keyboard and select next line below. Any solution to that?